# Right filter for rewriting page statuscode

Tags: filters, hooks, request-filter

I am new to developing wordpress plugins. But I am looking to write a fairly simple plugin.

I want to write a plugin that rewrites the returned status code based on some logic that consults a database. It can essentially be boiled down to an access plugin based on custom logic. When authorization fails I want to either return statuscode 403 or redirect to a login page.

But I am struggling to find the right place to hook in. And also the "correct" way of doing it.

The logic is based on a combination of the Page requested, the logged in user and that users role. Using these values I look up information in a database and either render some custom data or want to turn the user away. If the user is logged in I want to return a 403 but if the user is not logged in I want to return a 401. But is that even the right way of doing it in Wordpress? I am used to writing APIs and have never written a Wordpress plugin.

Should I render a text that says `Content not available!` instead of a 403 and redirect the user to the login page instead of a 401?

Ideally I would like to separate the logic that renders the data and the logic that authorizes. I would like that to be two different hooks or filters.

I have tried to add a filter on `http_response` but I can't get it to do anything. I am in doubt if I should call `apply_filter` myself or if Wordpress does that.

Where in the the Page lifecycle can I hook in after the page is known but not yet rendered to rewrite the page content and stop the rendering efter this rewrite.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: 3KB of letters and no way to understand you. Can you please represent your question in just three lines. Any piece of code? What have you tried?

Comment: That would be because I have never written a wordpress plugin before. I guess the gist of what I am trying to do is rewrite the response to replace everything with a text saying `Content not available`. I have read a lot of pages like this one: http://hookr.io/filters/http_response/. The doc states that I should run a piece of code `apply_filters` to run the sample. But I have no idea in what file I should add that code or in what function I should run this.